# Rails - Want to greyed out textfields/select_tags and enable only with checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have 5 Fields, and they should be greyed out(disabled). And you can only edit them if you tick the checkbox. How can i fix this ?

This is my View :

```
<%= form_tag({ :controller => 'orders', :action => 'submit_customer_settings' }, :method => 'post', :name => 'submit_customer_settings', :class => "row") do %>

      <table>
          <tr>
              <td class="col-lg-2" id ="customer_service_customer"  name=customer_service disabled="true"><%= select_tag(:customer_service_customer_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@customer_service_customers, 'id', 'name', params[:customer_service_customer_id].to_i), :class => "form-control input-sm") %></td>
              <td class="col-lg-2" id ="customer_service_project"  name=customer_service disabled="true"><%= select_tag(:customer_service_project_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@customer_service_projects, 'id', 'identifier', params[:customer_service_project_id].to_i), :class => "form-control input-sm") %></td>
              <td class="col-lg-2" id ="topic"  name=customer_service disabled="true"><%= text_field_tag :topic,  params[:topic], :class => "form-control input-sm"%></td> 

              <td>
              <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
              <input id="enable" type="checkbox" /> Enable
              </td>          

              <td class="col-lg-2" style="text-align: left;"><%= submit_tag t("next"), :class => "btn btn-primary"%></td>
              <td class="col-lg-2" ></td>
          </tr>
      </table>

      <br/>
      <div style="height:80px"></div>
    <%end%>
```

And the Javascript :

```
 $(function () {
    var $checkbox = $('[id^="enable"]'),
        $select = $('#customer_service_customer');
        $select = $('#customer_service_project');
        $select = $('#topic');


    $checkbox.change(function (e) {
        $select.prop('disabled', !$checkbox.is(':checked'));
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript applies the `disabled` property on the td, not on the `select` elements. This should work:

```
$(function () {
    var $checkbox = $('[id^="enable"]'),
    $select = $('#customer_service_customer select');
    $select = $('#customer_service_project select');
    $select = $('#topic select');


    $checkbox.change(function (e) {
        $select.prop('disabled', !$checkbox.is(':checked'));
    });
});
```